# Laravel 5.2 @foreach - invalid argument supplied

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to show data from 2 related database tables and I get the @foreach - invalid argument supplied error. does anyone know what I did wrong and know how to fix it?

Here is my Controller function

```
public function index()
{
   return view('Voorraad.index', [
    'voorraads' => Voorraad::all(),
    'Products' => Producten::all()
    ]);
}
```

as u can see i have a model "voorraad" and "producten" its a 1:n relation in the database "producten" beeing the 1 side and "voorraad" beeing the n side of the relation between them,

This is my "voorraad" model

```
class Voorraad extends Model

// Model Voorraad has the attributes, Aantal and Id;

 {
  protected $fillable = ['voorraadId','aantal'];
  protected $table = 'Voorraad';

public $timestamps = false;


/*
 * Voorraad can have multiple products;
*
 */

 public function Product()
 {
    return $this->HasMany('App\Producten', 'Producten_ProductenId');
 }
}
```

This is my "Producten" model

```
class Producten extends Model
 {

// model producten holdes the attribues naam, inkoopprijs, verkoopprijs, 

protected $fillable = ['productId','naam','inkoopprijs','verkoopprijs'];
protected $table = 'Producten';

public $timestamps = false;


//producten Belongs to "voorraad"

public function voorraad()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Voorraad', 'producten_productenId');
}
}
```

and this is the view I want to display my database models on:

```
@foreach($voorraads as $voorraad)

     <tr>
        <td>{{$voorraad->voorraadId}}</td>
        <td>{{$voorraad->aantal }}</td>
           @foreach($voorraad->producten as $products)
           <td>{{ $products->Naam }}</td>
           <td>{{ $products->InkoopPrijs }}</td>
           <td>{{ $products->VerkoopPrijs  }}</td>
          @endforeach
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
  @endforeach
```

[This is the dd of $voorraads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN9BH.png)

```
 This is my migration for the voorraad Table

 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('voorraad', function(blueprint $table)
    {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->string('naam');
          $table->foreign('Locaties_Id')
          ->reference('Id')
          ->on('locaties')
          ->onDelete('cascasde');
          $table->foreign('Producten_Id')
          ->reference('Id')
          ->on('producten')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

and this is my migrations for the producten table

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('producten', function(blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->decimal('inkoopprijs', '10, 2');
        $table->decimal('verkoopprijs', '10, 2');
        $table->foreign('Fabrieken_Id')
        ->reference('Id')
        ->on('fabrieken')
        ->onDelete('cascasde');
    });
}
```

Comment: It's close to impossible to tell what's wrong with the foreach unless the actual data that is looped is provided. In other words, dump `$voorraads` and add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within the Voorraad model, where you defined the relation:

```
public function Product()
{
   return $this->HasMany('App\Producten', 'Producten_ProductenId');
}
```

But in the view you try to access the relation by calling

`@foreach($voorraad->producten as $products)`

If you change the method in the model it should work

```
public function producten()
{
   return $this->HasMany('App\Producten', 'Producten_ProductenId');
}
```

Comment: thanks @trommelaap for this response, but when i changed the method name i got another error but this time i got this error: `code`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Producten.Producten_Id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Producten` where `Producten`.`Producten_Id` is null and `Producten`.`Producten_Id` is not null) do u have any idea what i need to change to my database?

Comment: The second argument for the producten method in the Voorraad model should be the name of the foreign key column in the producten table that relates to the Voorraad table. Perhaps voorrraad_id? Please post the migrations of the 2 tables.

Comment: i've put the migrations in the question @trommelaap, and Producten doesn't have a foreign key, but voorraad has the foreign key of producten_id, and what i want  to show is the producten with the "aantal" on my voorraad index page.